# Capistrano 3.1.0 Deployment issue with Rake >= 10.2.0

Tags: ruby, rake, capistrano, rvm-capistrano

I have installed RVM and Capistrano, but seem to be running into an error.

My Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'sass'
gem 'compass'
gem 'capistrano-rvm'
gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.1.0'
```

My Ruby version:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-darwin12.0]
```

Then I run:

```
$ cap install
mkdir -p config/deploy
create config/deploy.rb
create config/deploy/staging.rb
create config/deploy/production.rb
mkdir -p lib/capistrano/tasks
Capified
```

Then:

```
$ cap deploy:check
cap aborted!
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Rake::Task into String
/Users/ianjamieson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/capistrano-3.1.0/lib/capistrano/application.rb:15:in `run'
/Users/ianjamieson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/capistrano-3.1.0/bin/cap:3:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/ianjamieson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/cap:23:in `load'
/Users/ianjamieson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/cap:23:in `<main>'
/Users/ianjamieson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/ianjamieson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

The only cap command that returns anything is:

```
$ cap -V
Capistrano Version: 3.1.0 (Rake Version: 10.2.1)
$ cap -vT
cap deploy                         # Deploy a new release
cap deploy:check                   # Check required files and directories exist
cap deploy:check:directories       # Check shared and release directories exist
cap deploy:check:linked_dirs       # Check directories to be linked exist in shared
cap deploy:check:linked_files      # Check files to be linked exist in shared
cap deploy:check:make_linked_dirs  # Check directories of files to be linked exist in shared
cap deploy:cleanup                 # Clean up old releases
cap deploy:cleanup_rollback        # Remove and archive rolled-back release
cap deploy:finished                # Finished
cap deploy:finishing               # Finish the deployment, clean up server(s)
cap deploy:finishing_rollback      # Finish the rollback, clean up server(s)
cap deploy:log_revision            # Log details of the deploy
cap deploy:published               # Published
cap deploy:publishing              # Publish the release
cap deploy:revert_release          # Revert to previous release timestamp
cap deploy:reverted                # Reverted
cap deploy:reverting               # Revert server(s) to previous release
cap deploy:rollback                # Rollback to previous release
cap deploy:started                 # Started
cap deploy:starting                # Start a deployment, make sure server(s) ready
cap deploy:symlink:linked_dirs     # Symlink linked directories
cap deploy:symlink:linked_files    # Symlink linked files
cap deploy:symlink:release         # Symlink release to current
cap deploy:symlink:shared          # Symlink files and directories from shared to release
cap deploy:updated                 # Updated
cap deploy:updating                # Update server(s) by setting up a new release
cap install                        # Install Capistrano, cap install STAGES=staging,production
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capistrano 3.1.0 has a compatibility issue with Rake >= 10.2.0. I'm actually surprised `cap staging deploy:check` worked for you.

I've submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/pull/983) to get it fixed, but in the mean time you could lock your Gemfile to Rake 10.1.1.

Comment: Nice one! Can't believe this was the issue!! `$ cap` now returns `Stage not set, please call something such as 'cap production deploy', where production is a stage you have defined.`

Answer (score 1):

Don't know what's the problem but try running `bundle exec cap staging deploy:check`

Comment: Ah, that seems to work and also `cap staging` I guess I was used to not having to define `staging`. I thought it could default to that if nothing was entered, but perhaps not! Nice friendly error!